# Can a CHM file be re-built so all html files are local?

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, chm

Is there a way to take a .chm file that is already compiled, and rebuilt it so it's html files are stored locally? I do not have access to the installer that generated the chm file. The issue is that I am attempting to view the chm file on a work computer that is either blocking all web requests from the chm file itself, or the chm file is attempting to make get requests for the html documentation and is making it's requests through firewalled network ports. I don't know exactly which it is, but I can view the chm file perfectly on my personal computer. I would like to re-compile or rebuild the chm file so that it no longer has to make requests to collect the html files. I would like to store all html files within the chm file. I'd love to know if anyone knows of a way to do this. BTW, there is no "unblock" button in the file properties as referenced in other solutions to this problem... so this is a different issue.

[image: Very Similar to what I am seeing...]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short story - I think it is a long known security problem with blocked content of the CHM file. It does not have to be decompiled if this problem is solved first.

The blank screen you see may be a problem on your work computer because the CHM resides on the company network drive.

Another cause could be that you did not unblock the `PsTools.zip` first after the download (you mentioned "...there is no "unblock" button in the file properties as referenced in other solutions"). So search for the unblock button of the ZIP file first.

But sometimes you only have the CHM output file and nobody can locate the source files.

If you really decide to decompile there are different ways. It’s not always possible to recover all files and data you need in particular the project file *.hhp. *.hhc (TOC) and in the case of previous use *.hhk (index) are decompiled.

Please note - all HTML files are already stored in the CHM file and are only added as an external file for very special use cases. You'll lose all the CHM's features like TOC (Table of Contents), Index and Search if you decide to use pure HTML format.

The hh.exe is the viewer for CHM files in Windows and can not only display CHM files but also extract CHM files. No interface - just enter this into a command prompt or PowerShell window and amend as necessary.

```
  hh.exe -decompile <target_directory> <path>\<filename>.chm
```

For more info have a look at:

[Decompile CHM](https://www.help-info.de/kb/en/HTMLHelp/100007-hh-decompile-chm.html)

Comment: (toc is by default non binary so will be extracted as hhk?)

Comment: @Marco - see my edit "...if you decide to use pure HTML format."

Answer (score -1):

### About the blank topic problem

Usually this problem comes from the fact that the **CHM help file is placed on a networked or mapped drive**: the easiest solution is to move it to a local hard drive.
This can also happen when the file has been **downloaded from the Internet** and the file's property panel will show an "Unblock" button in that case.
Another possible explanation is that the file path **contains symbols such as "#" (sharp)** which somehow confuses the Microsoft HTML help viewer.
You can check this page for a detailed explanation: [The CHM documentation format only displays the table of contents without any topic content](https://support.helpndoc.com/en/support/solutions/articles/43000549682-the-chm-documentation-format-only-displays-the-table-of-contents-without-any-topic-content)

### Re-build this CHM help file, or convert it to another format

If you'd like to go that route, the easiest and fastest solution would be to use a [help authoring software such as HelpNDoc](https://www.helpndoc.com/), [Help+Manual](https://www.helpandmanual.com/) or [madcap Flare](https://www.madcapsoftware.com/products/flare/): they typically allow you to import an existing CHM help file, edit it as needed, and produce one or more output of the supported formats.
For example, see [how you can convert a CHM help file to a PDF document](https://www.helpndoc.com/step-by-step-guides/how-to-convert-a-chm-help-file-to-a-pdf-document/).